# Recalculate date difference based on exact dates

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 columns in my table firstdate and lastdate

firstdate is for example today (2020-1-22). 
lastday is plus 1 years minus 1 day (2021-1-21).

So my insert script is like:

```
INSERT INTO <table> (firstdate, lastdate) 
VALUES (current_date, current_date + interval '1 year -1 day')
```

Ok, so far so good. Now I want to extrapolate it to use it again.

My question is based on these 2 dates. How can i return the interval back again from these 2 dates?

When I use the Postgres function `age`, I get the following result: `0 years 11 months 30 days`.

I can't use this interval to make the right calculation because interval `0 years 11 months 30 days` is not the same as interval `1 years -1 days`.

So somehow I need to get back `1 years -1 days`

Comment: If you want to know what interval was used (in an insert) then store the interval as well.

Answer (score 0):

lastdate-firstdate gives you the interval between the dates.  You cannot get back the literal string you used to create the original interval.

Best regards,
Bjarni

Answer (score 0):

You can store the interval instead of lastdate then derive the lastdate when needed as column interval_value. So

```
select firstdate,first_date+interval_value lastdate ...
```

or if you have version 12, define lastdate as a virtual column. Then just select normally. Either way you have the necessary interval.